# Clearing a list - cleared data comes back

Tags: c#, winforms

i am build application who play Wireshark files and send the packets to the network card using pcapdot.net.

in my application i get directory root and add only the new files from the last 24 hours. first i am add all my files from the directory to List and then to my ListView. now after my application finished to play all my files i want to clear my List, clear my ListView and again search for now files from the last 24 hours and add to my ListView.
my problem is that if i choose folder with 2 files, the 2 files added and after the application finished to play this 2 files and the my `List<string>` and `ListView` is now empty the application add now not only this 2 files again, but this files several times anfd i cannot find what is the problem.

```
List<string> capturesList = null;
    string pathToSearch = null;
    DialogResult dialog;
lvFiles is my ListView
```

**add directory button**

```
private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    capturesList = new List<string>();
    dialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    tbAddDir.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    pathToSearch = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Search for pcap files...";
        groupBoxRootDirectory.Enabled = false;
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        addFiles();
    }
}
```

**and the add files:**

```
private void addFiles()
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        capturesList = SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.pcap",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            if (capturesList.Count != 0)
                AddFilesToListView(capturesList);
        });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**add files to my ListView:**

```
private void addFileToListBox(string filePath, string duration)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { new FileInfo(filePath).Name, duration, "Waiting" });
    item.Tag = new FileInfo(filePath).FullName;
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lvFiles.Items.Add(item); });
}

private void AddFilesToListView(List<string> filesList)
{
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    Editcap editcap = new Editcap();
    Capinfos capinfos = new Capinfos();
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
        (s1, e1) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count; i++)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filesList[i]);
                if (checkFileCreationDate(fileInfo))
                {
                    if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                    {
                        if (editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            addFileToListBox(fileInfo.FullName, capinfos.getFileDuration(fileInfo.FullName));
                        }
                        else if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            fileToAdd = editcap.getNewFileName(fileInfo.FullName);

                            if (new FileInfo(fileToAdd).Exists)
                            {
                                addFileToListBox(fileToAdd, capinfos.getFileDuration(fileToAdd));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
    (s1, e1) =>
    {

    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**start play button:**

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    playFiles();
}

playFiles function:

private void playFiles()
{
    lockButtons();
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count && shouldContinue; i++)
        {
            PcapFile pcapFile = new PcapFile();
            pcapFile.sendQueue(filePath, adapter);
        }
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            capturesList.RemoveRange(0, capturesList.Count);
            lvFiles.Items.Clear();
            addFiles();
            playFiles();
        });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}
```

after i am finish the playFiles function inside backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted i am clear all my lists and add the files again from my directory root and playFiles again:

```
        capturesList.RemoveRange(0, capturesList.Count);
        lvFiles.Items.Clear();
        addFiles();
        playFiles();
```

Comment: Well, where do you delete the files, or indicate that they shouldn't be used anymore?

Comment: after i am finish the playFiles function inside backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: I see you clearing the _lists_, but not the files from the filesystem.

Comment: ListView.Clear() did not remove the filesystem ? what do you mean filesystem ?

Comment: No. Why would it? It clears out the `ListView` - what is held in memory.

Comment: Can you come up with a better title for this?

Comment: and how can i clear it ?

Comment: "but this files several times" -  several times is how many? twice or more? Always the same multiple or something "random"?

Comment: i dont want to delete the file from the disk, only to search again the folder and add the files again, the application add in the first time the 2 files and the second time same file 6-7 times

Comment: Their is no guarantee that the `BackgroundWorker` threads started by playFiles(), addFiles() and addFilesToListView() will not run concurrently but there is no synchronization code around the Lists which are not threadsafe.  This could cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: maybe that's why i get different behavior almost every time, can i have example how to fix it ?

Comment: checkout MSDN or google 'c# Lists threading synchronization'.  Would you like me to add an answer with an example?

Comment: it will be great help if you add an answer (i am a new development)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding thread synchronization to the lists.  Below is one example you could use whenever iterating over or modifying your lists:

```
    lock (capturesList.SyncRoot) {

        /* perform iteration or modification */
        capturesList.Add("All other threads are waiting until i am finished");          

    }
```

Comment: i added lock on my capturesList and lvFiles every time i am add or remove and still strange behavior